# Pip just wont Install with Python

Tags: python, pip

I can see this has been asked a few times but I can't find a solution that works for me! No matter what I do, I can't get pip to work, I'm trying to install `Pillow`.

I know pip isn't installed because when I run:

```
pip help
```

I receive the message: "No module named 'pip._internal'; 'pip' is not a package".

When I run:

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

I receive the message: "Requirement already satisfied:"

I have:

- Reinstalled Python 3.11.1 adding it to my path with the check box.
- Using Python installer, I have Repaired and Modified the program.
- Using cmd, I tried to install pip with

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py.
```

I received the message: "Unknown error (0x80092012)"

Any help on what I'm doing wrong will be much appreciated.

Comment: You've tried running `python -m pip help`, right?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "I receive the message: "No module named 'pip._internal'; 'pip' is not a package"." This **does not** mean it isn't installed. It means the installation is broken. Please see the linked duplicate. The "repair and modify" option provided by the Python installer for Windows only looks after Python itself, not Pip. "Using cmd, I tried to install pip with" This **will not attempt to install** anything; it only downloads an installation script. (There should not be a `.` after the `.py` in the filename.)